# How to get a <ul> pop-up div to cover other <li> elements without using Javascript

Tags: css, navigation, html-lists

so i have this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/speeedracer/CGucm/ and as you can see when you mouse over any of the links across the top row, the popup div is under the list elements of the bottom row. anyone know how to get it to cover over the other page content? i changed the z-index to be really high so it appears on top, but it didn't work.

here's the drop-down box code:
`enter code here`.drop-box {
    display: none; 
    position: static;
    width: 400px; 
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 9999; 
    background: #e8dfc2;
}

*i know i have some visual spacing issues, but i just need a working mockup without it having to be perfect...yet.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`z-index` does not work with `position: static`. This is as if you had no position.

So changing your `position: absolute` will solve your problem and `z-index` will come into play.

Comment: woot! thank you very much! i never really understood what all the different options for that css property mean.

Comment: Here is the explanation: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).

Comment: No worries strenbeath. Make sure you upvote and give the correct answer. So if others have the same problem they'll know.